# spring pooled connection

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-mvc, hsqldb

Could you help me to find correct datasource for my spring-mvc application. At now I use HSQLDB database and coonect to using this bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}"
/>

in jdbc.properties:
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

But I'm pretty sure, that DriverManagerDataSource don't use pooled coonection. So, it cannot be used properly in web-applications. I tried to find other classes, but any of them in hsqldb.jar library couldn't be used as spring datasource, because they have different interfaces. I thinked to write adapter class to use it, bu I think more useful solution eists for my problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [DBCP's](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) for this.
And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525529/whats-the-proper-way-to-handle-jdbc-connections-with-spring-and-dbcp) has an example configuration.

Comment: @Ilnur it is a pooled connection. One of it's parameters is the driverClassName which references the actual (non-pooled) connection class

Comment: sure thing! Also, some people prefer c3p0 over DBCP, and there's various opinions about which is better. DBCP works for me and is easy.